# Crawling Website using Python Selenium and storing it as CSV file

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to crawl this website https://opencollective.com/discover
to get hold of all the project name and store those names on the csv file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = "/home/myname/Documents/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://opencollective.com/discover")

name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "CollectiveCard-name"]')
titles = [x.text for x in name] 
with open('discover_file.csv', mode='w') as discover_file:
    discover_writer = csv.writer(discover_file, delimiter = ',')
    discover_writer.writerow(titles)
```

But when I run the PDB on this code I am able to get the names as I require. Which is as below.

> /home/myname/Documents/GitHub_Project/test.py(16)()
>   -> chromedriver = "/home/myname/Documents/chromedriver"
>   (Pdb) n
>   /home/myname/Documents/GitHub_Project/test.py(19)()
>   -> driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
>   (Pdb) n
>   /home/myname/Documents/GitHub_Project/test.py(22)()
>   -> driver.get("https://opencollective.com/discover")
>   (Pdb) n
>   /home/myname/Documents/GitHub_Project/test.py(25)()
>   -> name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "CollectiveCard-name"]')
>   (Pdb) n
>   /home/myname/Documents/GitHub_Project/test.py(27)()
>   -> titles = [x.text for x in name]
>   (Pdb) name[0].text
>   u'webpack'
>   (Pdb) name[1].text
>   u'Babel'

Could someone please explain me why this happens and what needs to be done?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *I am able to get the names as I require* Than I'm not sure what is the question.

Comment: I am able to get the names of the project only in the pdb. and not as the output from the code.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions?

Comment: nope, no exceptions.

Comment: Le me put it this way, have I retrieved the project names properly in my code ?.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python debugger, but I don't see the last block in the output (writing to the CSV file). Are you sure this part run? You should also do global search for the file, maybe it's not where you expect it to be.

Comment: The file has been created right in the same folder as the code, but leaving that aside, even if I run a for loop to print out the names that were called, I am returned with a null tuple

Comment: Try to add some [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) `name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))` (see link for complete example).

Comment: How do you print `titles`?

Comment: The wait time solved the problem @Guy. Thanks :)